# Is there any rest testing tool which hosts the webservices and injects mocks in the facade layer?

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I would like to know is there any api/tool which automatically deploys ear/war/war-inside-ear and then injects mocks in the facade layer to make it suitable for testing.

I heard that rest assured api is one such api. But I did not come across tutorials or example which explains how to write code to deploy the ear/war/war-inside-ear in a default web server(netty/jetty) and test the web services.

Till now we are deploying our ear in jboss(without any mock data) and testing the web services using aur own custom apis.

P.S.

I have an ear which contains a war module. All my web service classes are in it.  To test the request and response of the web services, I am deploying the actual web services and other ejbs in a jboss instance which requires lot of effort and setup. And then I am testing the requests and responses of all web services.

I am looking for a tool which deploys the ear and inject mocks in the web service classes instead of initializing all the ejbs inside the ear. This will reduce my effort for the setup I have to do to get the ejbs run.

Comment: why are you mentioning the façade layer?  why would a tool know or care about a facade?

Comment: Facade layer I mean is my web service class to which all requests go

Comment: so why not say that?  it's difficult trying to figure out what you are really asking, being very specific is very helpful.

Comment: @TMcKeown edited the original question to add more description. Hopefully this should explain what I want.